# Installing IIS on Windows from Ansible

Tags: linux, windows, ansible, yaml

My ansible is configured on my host machine - Linux 16.06 LTS and i am successfully able to ping my server using the `ansible windows -m win_ping` command.

Now im trying to install IIS on my server. I have created a YAML file in my group_vars folder called installIIS.yml.

```
---
- name: Install IIS
  hosts: windows
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
   - win_feature:
     name: "windows"
     state: present
     restart: yes
     include_sub_features: yes
     include_management_tools: yes
```

and im running the yml file by: `root@SAUPRDSVR01:/etc/ansible# ansible-playbook group_vars/installIIS.yml`

and the error i received is

```
ERROR! 'include_sub_features' is not a valid attribute for a Task

The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/group_vars/installIIS.yml': line 6, column 6, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
   - win_feature:
     ^ here
```

Any help regarding this. I would also like to install antivirus, tripwire and also check for windows updates from ansible.

```
/etc/ansible# tree
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── group_vars
│   ├── installIIS.yml
│   ├── linux.yml
│   └── windows.yml
├── hosts
└── roles
```

Any help or links for this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the issue is the indent level where you are specifying the options for `win_feature`. The options should be indented under the `win_feature` module, as opposed to on the same level.

example:

```
---
- name: Install IIS
  hosts: windows
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
   - win_feature:
       name: "web-server"
       state: present
       restart: yes
       include_sub_features: yes
       include_management_tools: yes
```

[win_feature](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_feature_module.html) documentation for the reference

Answer (score -1):

if you are installing IIS then name of win_feature should be correct:

```yaml
- name: Install IIS
  hosts: windows
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
   - win_feature:
       name: Web-Server
       state: present
       restart: yes
       include_sub_features: yes
       include_management_tools: yes
```

Comment: only submit unique answer. if someone already posted similar answer before you than upvote that person to encourage his effort